How to allow gitlab CI/CD to access RDS
I have a CI/CD pipeline on gitlab in which i run mvn tests where I use access to RDS tables.
How am I supposed to adjust VPC inbound and outbound policies to allow gitlab CI/CD pipeline use it? When I change to allow IPv4 to 0.0.0.0/0 it works correctly, but when I change it, it fails to connect with DB, so surely this is the problem. I tried to find some IP ranges but they are outdated, also seen some static IPs of google cloud instances that are used in pipeline but probably this is not the way to solve that.

Are you using the cloud (hosted) version of Gitlab ? Or are you hosting your own? For the cloud version, take a look at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/#ip-range

@FrankSchmitt I am using hosted version of gitlab with my private container in container registry, but adding these IP ranges doesn't solve the issue.

What "IP ranges is outdated" ? also what do you mean by "VPC inbound and outbound policies" ? security group , NACL ?
